# I want to study Numerical linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Would you like to recommend a book to me?
the proof is explicit and easy to understand is preferred.

Comment: What is your background? Are you an undergraduate student?  Graduate?  High school?  Have you already taken some linear algebra course?  Do you have any particular motivation for learning this material, i.e. any application in mind?

Comment: I will be a graduate next year and I have leaned the course names 'numerical linear algebra' including 'LU,backward error,classical iteration,qr for symmetric,least square'.I want to study further.but I find the book writed by Artkinson is hard to understand.@Omnomnomnom

Comment: In addition,I found the Sauer is easy to understand,But I don't think it is deep enough.@Omnomnomnom

Comment: Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan and Fundamentals of Matrix Computations by Watkins are excellent books to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau